# SQL select date range by month and year

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select date range from this query?

E.g : From Month('2017-05-22') And Year(date1) = Year('2017-05-22') 
to Month('2018-05-22') And Year(date1) = Year('2018-05-22')

My current query :

```
SELECT 
  date1
FROM 
  data
WHERE 
  Month(date1) = Month('2018-05-22') And Year(date1) = Year('2018-05-22')
```

Comment: share your sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd convert those literals to dates using [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT MONTH(date1)
FROM   data
WHERE  date1 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2017-05-22', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-05-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note that `between` is **inclusive** on the first argument and **exclusive** on the second, so I bumped the day to the 23rd.

Comment: It works but i need only for month, for example when i pass '2018-05-22' it will display all day or maybe month only in May.

Comment: @AmirulFahmi You could extract the month from the result by calling `month`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN condition to retrieve values within a date range.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_details
WHERE order_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

This MySQL BETWEEN condition example would return all records from the order_details table where the order_date is between Feb 1, 2014 and Feb 28, 2014 (inclusive). It would be equivalent to the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_details
WHERE order_date >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE)
AND order_date <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Comment: thx..but how do i display whenever it cast like '2018-02-22' it will display as Feb and so on

Comment: date range selection and month showing is different , you can easily showing day, month or year from any date values mysql has all type of function DAY('2008-05-15') it will return 15, MONTH('2009-05-18') it will return 5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy-mm') as yyyymm,
       max(notenum) - min(notenum) + 1 as notenum_range
FROM your_table_name
WHERE systemts >= to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
      systemts < to_date('2018-07-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy-mm');
```

Comment: is this for oracle sql only?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @monthfrom int=null,
    @yearfrom int=null,
    @monthto int=null,
    @yearto int=null

/**Region For Create Date on Behalf of Month & Year**/
    DECLARE @FromDate DATE=NULL
    DECLARE @ToDate DATE=NULL

    SET @FromDate=DateAdd(day,0, DateAdd(month, @monthfrom - 1,DateAdd(Year, @yearfrom-1900, 0)))
    SET @ToDate=DateAdd(day,-1, DateAdd(month, @monthto - 0,DateAdd(Year, @yearto-1900, 0)))
/**Region For Create Date on Behalf of Month & Year**/

SELECT DISTINCT month ,Year FROM  tbl_Att
WHERE  (DATEADD(yy, year - 1900, DATEADD(m, Month - 1, 1 - 1)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate, 102) AND 
CONVERT(DATETIME, @ToDate, 102))
```